# Wagtail Customising User Account Settings Form With One-to-One Model

Tags: python, django, model, wagtail, one-to-one

I have a model in my app called "portal", in `portal/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

@register_snippet
class StaffRoles(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=154, unique=True, help_text="Create new staff roles here, these roles an be assigned to 'staff' users.")
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('role'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Staff Role"
        verbose_name_plural = "Staff Roles"

@register_snippet
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(StaffRoles, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + " " + str(self.user.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Staff"
        verbose_name_plural = "Staff"


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_superuser:
        Staff.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Any new superuser is automatically given the `Staff` model. Any existing (non superuser) user can also be added as `Staff`.

I want Staff members to be able to set a `bio` and a `role`. Roles can be added through the Snippets page in Wagtail admin.

Right now, `Staff` is registered as a snippet, this means any Staff member can edit another Staff member's Staff attributes.

I want to customise the Wagtail User Account Settings by adding a form to each user's respective Staff attributes. This way, I can lock out the Staff snippet so each user who has a `Staff` object linked to their `User` model can change only their own `Staff` fields/attributes.

Following the Wagtail documentation from [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_account_settings.html), I first created the file `portal/forms.py` with the content:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from wagtail.users.models import UserProfile

from .models import Staff

class CustomStaffSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        exclude = []
```

And another file `portal/wagtail_hooks.py` with the contents:

```
from wagtail.admin.views.account import BaseSettingsPanel
from wagtail.core import hooks

from .forms import CustomStaffSettingsForm

@hooks.register('register_account_settings_panel')
class CustomStaffSettingsPanel(BaseSettingsPanel):
    name = 'custom_staff'
    title = "Staff settings"
    order = 500
    form_class = CustomStaffSettingsForm
    form_object = 'profile'
```

This doesn't work as intended. When accessing "Account settings" and scrolling down to the "Staff settings" I can see the `CustomStaffSettingsForm` as intended. Although the correct user is pre-selected in the `User` field, I can still select other users. Also, the stored values for `bio` and `roles` aren't being retrieved and new values aren't being saved.

Below are the `Staff Roles` registered in the snippets page:
[image]

Below is the `Staff` model for the user "sid" in the snippets page:
[image]

Below is what the `Staff settings` section in the "Account settings" looks like.
[image]

As you can see, although the `User` dropdown is selected to the right user, I can still click and select another user. The `bio` and `roles` fields aren't filled with the correct values from the snippets page and not shown in the picture, filling and saving values doesn't work.

I hope my question is as detailed as possible, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of digging, I managed to answer my own question.

1. A `related_name` needs to be added with the value of `profile` to Staff.user. This prevents the `'User' object has no attribute 'profile'` error message

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    ...
```

2. We need to exclude the `user` field from the `CustomStaffSettingsForm`. This is to prevent users to select a different user and change another user's `Staff` fields.

```
class CustomStaffSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        exclude = ["user"]
```

3. The tricky part (at least for me) was to render the correct instance of the form, in other words, if a user named "sid" is accessing this form, they need to be able to see their own `Staff` fields which are stored and also be able to change the stored values. To achieve this, I had to override the `get_form` method which `CustomStaffSettingsPanel` inherited form Django's `BaseSettingsPanel`. It's easier for me to paste the entire `wagtail_hooks.py` contents here below.

```
from wagtail.admin.views.account import BaseSettingsPanel
from wagtail.core import hooks

from .forms import CustomStaffSettingsForm

@hooks.register('register_account_settings_panel')
class CustomStaffSettingsPanel(BaseSettingsPanel):
    name = 'custom_staff'
    title = "Staff settings"
    order = 300
    form_class = CustomStaffSettingsForm
    form_object = 'profile'

    def get_form(self):
        """
        Returns an initialised form.
        """
        kwargs = {
            'instance': self.request.user.profile,
            'prefix': self.name
        }

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return self.form_class(self.request.POST, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.form_class(**kwargs)
```

The key part of the code above is `'instance': self.request.user.profile`. Passing this argument into `self.form_class` results in the correct user's stored `Staff` fields and values to be retrieved and stored correctly.

This solution allows me to make sure superusers who are also registered as `Staff` can edit their own `Staff` fields and have access to others, this is a functionality which cannot be achieved easily with Snippets.

As `Staff` is no longer registered as a Snippet, we lose access to change another user's `Staff` fields. This can be fixed by adding the following in `portal/admin.py`:

```
admin.site.register(Staff)
```

Only superusers who had been created via `python manage.py createsuperuser` or has had `staff_status` set to true can access the Django Admin interface at `http://localhost:8000/django-admin`. Unlike Snippets, this way can be used to allow only the Django superuser staff to access and modify Staff fields.

What about non-superusers who are registered as `Staff`? Non-superusers cannot access the Wagtail admin, therefore they cannot access the Account Settings page. In most cases, this shouldn't be a problem as the ideal use-case is where only the superusers can be set as Staff. If you want to set non-superusers as `Staff` you might have to create your own views and forms so the user can change their `Staff` fields outside of Wagtail admin.